# Round bracket apparent syntactic error in C++ but compiler not complaining

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, g++

Why the compiler (g++-4.9) is not complaining on this notation?

```
double d=(4,5,6);
```

and if I debug it, the value of `d` is `6`?
What do the round brackets mean in this expression?
P.S.
I've enabled C++11

Answer (score 2):

This uses the comma operator, which (without overloading) just evaluates the left-hand expression, throws away the result, and returns the result of the right-hand expression.

Since the expressions `4` and `5` have no side-effects, your code is equivalent to:

```
double d = 6;
```

Answer (score 2):

This is [comma operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other).

> In a comma expression E1, E2, the expression E1 is evaluated, its
>   result is discarded, and its side effects are completed before
>   evaluation of the expression E2 begins (note that a user-defined
>   operator, cannot guarantee sequencing).

For `(4,5,6)`, first evaluate expression `4`, disregard its return value and complete any side-effects (nothing here indeed), then do the same thing with `5`, then evaluate the last expression `6`, returning the type and the result of this evaluation.